# Two identical strings return false while one string received from a PHP response

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

I got a strange problem, when I receive a response from a PHP page, store it in a string variable in Java and try to compare it with identical string that I typed, it return false from some reason.

I am trying to make  a login class that validate simply if the user details are stored on MySQL.

This `if("User Found".equals(response))` statement returns false even that the response contain equal contents.

Here is the Java and PHP codes:

```
void login(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.200.10.100:8080/login.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",loginInputs[0]));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",loginInputs[1])); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        httpresponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });


        if("User Found".equals(response)){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });                     
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();               
        }
    });
}
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php


  if (isset($_POST['Name']) && isset($_POST['Password'])) {

    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
     // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/connect.php';
    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE Name='$name' AND Password='$Password'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
          {
           echo "User Found";

          }
   else {

        echo "Not Found";

        }
     }   
?>
```

I read a lot of suggestions and tried to change many things but couldn't succeed. Anyway I think the problem caused by unmatched string encoded type, but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Hi there. I've fixed up the code formatting and case errors in your post. Just so you know, Stack Overflow tends to be regarded specifically _not_ as a chat-room or forum; posts here are for posterity, and so readers tend to appreciate correct use of capitals and punctuation. It doesn't have to be perfect, but a little effort sometimes encourages people to answer `:)`.

Comment: Are you sure there is no newline/space at the end/beginning of the file? You can remove that or try `response = response.trim();`

Comment: I am sorry. it is my first time to post a question.
I will check the option of using MySQLi.

Comment: There is newline but even when i took it out with substring function the statement returned false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet worked for me:

```
String TempString = new String(response.substring(2,12).toString());

if("User Found".equals(TempString)) {
    // other actions here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `compareTo()`?

**Edit:**

It would be a better solution if the php code returned an int. Ex: if user is found, return 1 else return 0. 
Then in login() function for each digit retured display the message. It is easier comparing integers than strings.

Comment: i tried with compareto ("User Found".compareTo(response)==0)
and it returns false.

Comment: It would be a better solution if the php code returned an int. Ex: if user is found, return 1 else return 0. Then in login() function for each digit retured display the message.

Comment: I fixed it:


     String TempString=new String(response.substring(2,12).toString());
     if("User Found".equals(TempString))
     {...}